# Combinatorics Olympiad problem - Sort out a schedule

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Interesting problem from a $2000$ St. Petersburg school olympiad.

*There are $109$ soldiers in a camp. Every night three of them go on watch patrol. Prove that it can be arranged so that after a while, every pair of soldiers has shared watch exactly three times.*

I think I'm missing the key insight here.

Comment: Perhaps the idea of a Steiner Triple System is a place to start: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinerTripleSystem.html  and  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system

Comment: It will take a little over 16 years.  Surely by then some of the soldiers will have left the service, so I would say it is not possible.

Comment: As Joseph said, a Steiner Triple system exists (as $109 = 1 \mod 6$, proved by Kirkman). Taking 3 copies of that should solve this, I believe. Or is there a condition that no patrol can repeat?

Comment: You sure this is a school olympiad question.

Comment: @Uma: yes. In Russia.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the following does the trick and that the $109$ is really a red herring, and that the problem has a solution for each odd 
$n \ge 3.$

Suppose $n=2m+1$ and consider the triples $(i,i+j,i+2j)$ where $i=1,2,3,\ldots,(2m+1)$ and $j=1,2,3,\ldots, m.$ We can construct a
$(2m+1) \times m $ array of triples with $(i,i+j,i+2j)$ in the $i$th row and $j$th column. We work modulo $2m+1.$

For example here's a solution for $n=9.$

$$\begin{array} {cccc}
 (1,2,3) & (1,3,5) & (1,4,7) & (1,5,9) \\
 (2,3,4) & (2,4,6) & (2,5,8) & (2,6,1) \\
 (3,4,5) & (3,5,7) & (3,6,9) & (3,7,2) \\
 (4,5,6) & (4,6,8) & (4,7,1) & (4,8,3) \\
 (5,6,7) & (5,7,9) & (5,8,2) & (5,9,4) \\
 (6,7,8) & (6,8,1) & (6,9,3) & (6,1,5) \\
 (7,8,9) & (7,9,2) & (7,1,4) & (7,2,6) \\
 (8,9,1) & (8,1,3) & (8,2,5) & (8,3,7) \\
 (9,1,2) & (9,2,4) & (9,3,6) & (9,4,8)
\end{array}$$

The number of triples = $m(2m+1)= { 2m+1 \choose m } = $ the number of distinct pairs of integers in $S= \{ 1,2,3,\ldots,2m+1 \} $ and all triples are unique, where the order of the elements is taken into account. (For suppose $(x,y,z)$ is in our array, then $x=i,y=i+j$ and $z=i+2j$ for some $i,j$ and thus if $x<y$ this triple is in the $x$th row and $(y-x)$th column, and if $x>y$ it is in the $x$th row and $(y-x + 2m+1)$th column. So its position is uniquely determined by its elements.

Moreover, if $(x,y,z)=(i,i+j,i+2j)$ is in the array then none of $(x,z,y),(z,y,x)$ and $(y,x,z)$ can be in the array, for if one of the positions of the elements is fixed the latter three triples cannot obey the construction rule, that its elements increase by $j,$ since we know that $x,$ $y$ and $z$ increase by $j.$

Now consider a pair of integers $(a,b),$ which appears in a given triple, $(a,b,c)$. There cannot exist another triple in the array $(a,b,d),$ say, with $c \ne d$ since $c$ is uniquely determined by $a$ and $b.$

The pair $(a,b)$ cannot appear in more than three triples, in whatever order (we've already noted that we cannot have both $(a,b,c)$ and $(b,a,c)$ hence the three and not six), since the remaining element is uniquely determined by $a$ and $b.$ However, it cannot appear in less than three triples since the number of triples equals the number of pairs of distinct integers in
$S,$ so this would mean that another pair must appear in more than three triples, a contradiction.

Thus we have a solution for any odd $n \ge 3.$

So a solution for $n=11$ is:

$$\begin{array} {ccccc}
 (1,2,3) & (1,3,5) & (1,4,7) & (1,5,9) & (1,6,11) \\
 (2,3,4) & (2,4,6) & (2,5,8) & (2,6,10) & (2,7,1)\\
 (3,4,5) & (3,5,7) & (3,6,9) & (3,7,11) & (3,8,2) \\
 (4,5,6) & (4,6,8) & (4,7,10) & (4,8,1) & (4,9,3) \\
 (5,6,7) & (5,7,9) & (5,8,11) & (5,9,2) & (5,10,4) \\
 (6,7,8) & (6,8,10) & (6,9,1) & (6,10,3) & (6,11,5) \\
 (7,8,9) & (7,9,11) & (7,10,2) & (7,11,4) & (7,1,6) \\
 (8,9,10) & (8,10,1) & (8,11,3) & (8,1,5) & (8,2,7) \\
 (9,10,11) & (9,11,2) & (9,1,4) & (9,2,6) & (9,3,8) \\
 (10,11,1) & (10,1,3) & (10,2,5) & (10,3,7) & (10,4,9) \\
 (11,1,2) & (11,2,4) & (11,3,6) & (11,4,8) & (11,5,10)

\end{array}$$

Note that I'm not using Steiner triples, as $11 \ne 6k+1$ or $6k+3.$

Comment: Excellent.

Comment: Nice solution !

Comment: I know it's late but can you explain the motivation behind the $(i, i+j, i+2j)$ part? What made you construct such triples?