# China Girls Math Olympiad (CGMO) 2002

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

There are 3n girl students who took part in a summer camp. There were three girl students to be on duty every day. When the summer camp ended, it was found that any two of the 3n students had been on duty on the same day exactly once.
(1) When n = 3, is there any arrangement satisfying the requirement above. Prove your conclusion. 
(2) Prove that n is an odd number.

Comment: Do you mean that given any pair of students, there was exactly one day on which they were both on duty? How many days are there in a summer?

Comment: I think that's correct: any pair were both on duty on exactly one day. The problem didn't say how many days in total, but I think that's implied by this condition and "there were three girl students to be on duty every day".

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15995/combinatorics-olympiad-problem-sort-out-a-schedule It is difficult for me to believe that they copied this(being China Math's Olympiad), although I find somewhat difficult that they came up with the same problem.

Comment: @chubakueno It is from CGMO. Note that 2002 was the first year that CGMO started. The question is different from the one your stated (not a duplicate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, it is the [9-point affine plane](http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m4220/h2lec2.html), where each line segment represents a "day" and each vertex is a girl.
2. Assume $n$ is even.  Each person is on duty with 2 other people each day, and so the amount of people a person works with is divisible by 2.  However, there are $n-1$ people to work with, and $n$ is even $\rightarrow\leftarrow$